# Equicontinuity question.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

Is the family of function $\frac{y^2}{y^2 + k^2} $ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ equicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$? I know the definition of equicontinuity, but the k is throwing me off, as I'm used to having integers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what do you get for $y = 0$ and $y=k$ (assuming $k \ne 0$)?

By the way, it's **equicontinuity**, not **equacontinuity**.

Comment: oh, that's easy. I don't know why I didn't notice that earlier. Thanks!